# Symfony 2 optional API Key authentication

Tags: php, symfony, security, authentication, firewall

I've followed the official docs to set up API key authentication for a certain URL pattern ([Sf2.7 API Key auth docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html)).

The APIA Key firewall is defined before the main (normal login) firewall and it works.

However, I'm struggling because I would like to **use the main firewall** when the API Key (`?apikey=StrongCoffee`) **is not set at all** so that the users would be redirected to the login page.

I was trying to to do that with the firewall (no success), and then tried the `ApiKeyAuthenticator::createToken` returning null solution (which does not work contrary to what the docs says...)

`security.yml`:

```
api_key: /specialurl/.* # api key firewall that works
    stateless: true
    simple_preauth:
        authenticator: api_key_authenticator
        provider: api_key_user_provider

main: 
    pattern: ^/... # main firewall that works
```

Everything else looks like the Symfony 2 docs states.

Where do I have to look into? Can I solve this only on `security.yml` or somewhere else?

Comment: if youre using 2.8> have a look at [guard](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/guard-authentication.html).  its by far the easiest way of making a conditional authentication system.

Comment: I'm on 2.7... and can't migrate quickly

Comment: no its 2.8+ only.  Its not that big a jump, and well worth it.

Comment: Maybe, but impossible right at the moment. Still, i would like a solution for 2.7... there must be one ! :p